# Deleted_by is not changing while i delete a data;

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-7, laravel-9

I want to have fields created_by,updated_by and deleted_by and want to update these fields automatically. created_by,updated_by is working but deleted_by is not working.

in my model

```
use SoftDeletes;
    protected static function boot() {
            parent::boot();
    
            static::creating(function ($model) {
                $model->created_by = auth()->id();
                $model->updated_by = NULL;
                $model->deleted_by = NULL;
            });
    
            static::updating(function ($model) {
                $model->updated_by = auth()->id();
                $model->deleted_by = NULL;
            });
    
            static::deleting(function ($model) {
                $model->deleted_by = auth()->id();
            });
        }
```

And in my migration file

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('suppliers', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('contact_person_name');
            $table->string('country')->nullable();
            $table->text('address')->nullable();
            $table->string('contact')->nullable();
            $table->string('email')->nullable();
            $table->string('created_by')->nullable();
            $table->string('updated_by')->nullable();
            $table->string('deleted_by')->nullable();
            $table->softDeletes();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Likely this is due to how you are deleting the suppliers model.  If you are using a mass delete statement like :

```
 Supplier::where('id', $id)->delete();
```

It will not fire the `deleting` method on the `boot`(), as the delete is done directly on the DB.

Try:

```
Supplier::find($id)->delete()
```

Here the delete action is performed on the model, and thus will trigger the `deleting` method, and write your `deleted_by` as needed.

**Edit**

I wonder about the timing of the Laravel `deleting()` method in the `boot()`.  I would expect it to be the same as the `creating()` and `updating()` methods, but I don't know what you have before this in the code.  To avoid any issue, please try to explicitly set the variable (this assumes the event is fired and you have gotten around the mass assignment issue noted above):

```
static::deleting(function ($model) {
     $model->deleted_by = auth()->id();
     $model->save(); // Try this to force the update regardless of timing
 });
```

Comment: my delete function in controller is :

public function destroy(supplier $supplier)
    {
        try{
            $supplier->delete();
            return redirect()->route('supplier.index')->with('success', 'Supplier is deleted successfully');
        }catch(Exception $e){
            return redirect()->back()->withErrors($e->getMessage());
        }
    }

Comment: Is the function actually working?  IE can you see the `deleted_at` column **not** null on the database?

Comment: The function is working and when i delete an item time is set but deleted_by is not changing

Comment: I know this is crazy since you've already got the model via injection, but for testing, please try: `Supplier::find($supplier->id)->delete();` just to see if you can trigger the `deleting` boot method from your `destroy()` method.

Comment: Tried But not working

Comment: OK, sorry its not working.  It looks like you are doing it all correctly.  So, let's look at something else.  Please see my edited answer and please try adding that line of code.

Comment: It worked using $model->saveQuitely();